# Posting and executing a string as PHP?

Tags: php

I'm building an application that's self-hosted, and I'd like to have some form of licensing to minimize fraudulent downloads/distribution.

Of course, I'm well aware that being self-hosted someone could simply rip out all license features from the source-code, but the con's of using a compiler like Zend Guard or ionCube far outweigh the pro's in my opinion - nonetheless I'd like to have some basic form of license security.

What I originally had in mind to do was: user logs in  with license on app -> app posts license to my server -> server sends a response via a `HTTP GET` request -> app evaluates response, and if license is valid sets a value in a session variable (A), if invalid returns to login screen with an error.

The problem with this is, the evaluation of response/session setting is readily available in a application file, so if the user knows a little PHP and checks in on that source code, they'll realize all they'll need to do is set a session themselves with a particular `$_SESSION['_valid_license']` value, and they'll be good to go.

What I was considering doing to make it a little less easy was (if possible) to post PHP back as a response, and then have the application file execute it, for example:

**My original code:**

```
$response = $_GET['response'];

if($response == "fjdkuf9") {
start_session();
$_SESSION['_valid_license'] = "YES";
header("Location:" . $rp . "/admin/");
} else {
header("Location:" . $rp . "/login/?err=1");
}
```

**My new concept:**

```
$response = $_POST['response'];
str_replace("\", "", $response);
```

*With the following being posted as `response`:*

```
start_session();
\$_SESSION[\'_valid_license\'] = \"YES\";
header(\"Location:\" . \$rp . \"/admin/\");
```

Would that execute `$response` as actual PHP code after `str_replace()`? If possible, this would be great, as it would mean evaluation would be done on my server rather than within the self-hosted app itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution is just as insecure as the first. here's what I would do:

1. Your application POSTS to your server a serial number or some other identifying information.
2. Your server validates the serial number against the user's account or whatever and returns a unique response.
3. If that response is successful, you allow the user to continue. Obviously you'd want to implement some sort of caching mechanism here so you're not having to hit you server on every page view.

Putting the responsibility of validation on your server instead of self-hosted code is much more secure. You would need to encrypt the data that is sent BTW so that someone couldn't simply emulate the success response, but you get the idea.

Comment: Was more about obfuscation based security than legitimate security, and the session (session variable more specifically) was acting as the caching mechanism until the browser closed (but perhaps there's something better/less obvious I could do - as I'm evaluating whether `$_SESSION['_valid_license']` is  false and then redirecting them to the login page if so, which might be too obvious?). I'm planning, in theory anyway, to make most of the major functions within the script make some kind of call (or even be included from my server), so that as soon as a license is gone - application breaks.

Comment: If you encrypt the returned response and write it to disk, you'll be fine. Then, you'd just need to verify it once per week or something. Otherwise, your session idea would be fairly secure. I just definitely wouldn't advise putting the burden of verification on the client side.